# Gradle Build Successfully without Error but Still shows error on the build.gradle (app) Page

Tags: android, gradle, build

I have search all through the internet to solve this problem but i couldn't get a solution.
After syncing my Project, the gradle runs without any error but when i open the build.gradle file, it shows an error by underlining this line `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'` on the build.gradle (app) page. It shows this when i check for more info.

[image: This is the error information]

This is My complete gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'Lagchat'
            keyPassword 'HomeAlone'
            storeFile file('C:/Users/WESLEY/Desktop/APKBuild/android.jks')
            storePassword 'HomeAlone'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.classics.classics"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 10
        versionName "1.0.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support .test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }
    productFlavors {
        free {
            minSdkVersion 17
            applicationId 'com.classics.classics'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            targetSdkVersion 25
            testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
            versionCode 10
            versionName '1.0.3'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //firebase

    //Facebook

    //others
    compile project(':emoticon')
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.5'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.rxrelay:rxrelay:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is my complete file for build.gradle (project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

What to Note:
I was using this `compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'` before i changed them to `26` and `26.0.1` respectively because i was getting this error `Error:(15, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.` when i sync the gradle.

What can i do to make this project run without any error. Obviously to stop showing error on the build.gradle (app) even after successful building of gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error you're facing says

> All com.android.support libraries must use the same version specification

But you have many modules of this group referring different versions.

You have dependencies for `firebase` and if you run `gradle app:dependencies` you can see the following dependencies tree

```
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|         |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 -> 27.0.1
|         |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.1
|         |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.1
```

So firebase refers `com.android.support` libraries with `27.0.1` version

So you need to update your dependencies in order to align your project.

Then change:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
```

with

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'
```

After that you also need to update your `compileSdkVersion`

Change

```
compileSdkVersion 26
```

with

```
compileSdkVersion 27
```

And in the end

```
+--- com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.5
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1 -> 27.0.1
```

`support-v13` is referenced with version `25.3.1`

So add in your dependencies the line

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.0.1'
```

So that the gradle's resolution strategy can choose this higher version

**RECAP**, your dependencies should change this way:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.0.4'
    ...
}
```

Don't forget `compileSdkVersion 27`

Comment: Thanks for your time @RobertoMartucci How do i update my dependencies?

Comment: I wrote the lines that you should change with the new ones. Just follow the steps I suggested :)

Comment: It said missing platform for android-27. And says install missing platform.
I am currently installing it

`To install:
- Android SDK Platform 27 (platforms;android-27)
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 27 (revision: 1)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-27_r01.zip`

Comment: Yes, you should do it if you can